# VBoxManage Clonemedium disk

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04, disk-cloning

For context, I'm trying to shrink a specific virtualbox image virtual disk size because I don't want to to dedicate 120Gb of storage whenever someone tries to add it to their own machine. I've compacted my original image with zerofree, and then cloning the image using the clonemedium command to a smaller disk. When I look at the amount of space being used on the original image, it should all fit in the smaller image. However, when I launch the new image I get this error warning on boot up.

[Warning on bootup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfHdy.png)

I'm not exactly sure what to do from here. Is my approach just incorrect? Or have I executed something incorrectly?